# How to flush all ssh server data before the server shutdown?

Tags: linux, ssh, systemd

I have an embedded Linux OS control box that runs an application, which is started as a **systemd** service.  The application monitors the state of a switch.

At the same time, I am logged in the control box via an **ssh client** shell over Ethernet from a linux PC, monitoring the **systemd journalctl** output for any logs by the application.

When the switch state is found to be OFF, the application logs the event with the **systemd journaled** service by printing a message.  Consequently, the message gets logged by the **systemd journaled** service and saved on a non-volatile file.

After printing the message the application executes **system("poweroff")**.

Consequently, the ssh session is terminated quickly enough without receiving the message printed to the **journalctl output** at the ssh client side.  At the same time the message is successfully logged by the **systemd journaled** service and saved on the non-volatile file.

With this in mind, I am wondering if there was a specific way to postpone the execution of the **system("poweroff")** command until all the journalctl log data is transferred/flushed out of the **ssh output buffer**.  And by a specific I mean not an arbitrary **sleep()** call before the **system("poweroff")**.

Comment: What is your goal? Simply that you want to see that certain log message in the SSH session before issue the poweroff command?

Comment: The goal is to be sure that the log message indicating, say, power-off condition is sent out across the ssh link before the final system("poweroff") call.

Comment: Have you come across [this]
 (http://www.derkeiler.com/Newsgroups/comp.security.ssh/2005-03/0056.html), linked in a Server Fault answer?

Answer (score 0):

What about adding a line to the shutdown script that echos the output of tail -n1 of the non-volatile file?

Comment: Did you want to add this as a comment?

Comment: I can't, don't have enough reputation.

Comment: I do not think echoing the output of tail -n1 of the non-volatile file would help because when that call returns there would not be a guarantee that the log message has been sent out across the ssh link so that final system("shutdown") call can be safely executed without possibility of loosing ssh log data.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear why it should be guaranteed that the message is seen on the other end of the SSH session, and even if we accept it must be guaranteed, I still don't understand why a few seconds delay of the shutdown is critical (which could be achieved with *sleep()*), but you could take another approach

If the one or at least one SSH connection is always open to the server, you could initiate the shutdown from SSH session when the log message is written into the file.

```
tail -f path/to/file |  sed '/^regex pattern$/ q' && command_to_execute_after_match
```

Comment: No, having at least one SSH connection is always open to the server is not an option as the SSH connection only monitoring and not controlling the functioning of the server.

Comment: What is needed, I think, a way to make a call to a function that will send the message over the SSH link, i.e. send all accumulated data up until that moment, and only return when all the date have been sent out.